# Javascript Method Dispatch Process

Tags: javascript, methods, dispatch

Can anyone explain the process JavaScript goes through when a method is called to select which function is run? Most resources online I could find explain how to achieve specific behaviours  using JavaScript object, but not the general principle behind how method dispatch works in JavaScript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Method dispatch" is actually just property lookup, because "methods" in JavaScript are just functions used via object properties. (More about that on my blog: [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html))

When you write:

```
obj.prop
```

the JavaScript engine looks at the `obj` object to see if it has a property with the name `"prop"`. If it does, the value of that property is used. If it doesn't, the engine looks the the prototype object for `obj` to see if *it* has a property with that name. If so, it uses the value of it. If not, it looks at *that* object's prototype. Rinse, repeat, until it runs out of prototype objects.

There is **no** "method signature" matching of any kind as in some languages that allow method overloading. JavaScript doesn't have method overloading. There can only be one propety attached to an object with a given name.

Let's look at an example:

```
function Thing() {
}
Thing.prototype.test = function() {
    return "Thing#test";
};

var t = new Thing();
t.own = function() {
    return "My own";
};
```

Now let's play with `t`:

```
console.log(t.own());  // Logs "My own"
```

For the expression `t.own`, the engine looks at `t` to see if it has a property called `"own"`. It does, and so the value of that property (a function) is used. The `()` after it *calls* that function, which returns `"My own"`, and we're done.

```
console.log(t.test()); // Logs "Thing#test"
```

For the expression `t.test`, the engine looks at `t` to see if it has a property called `"test"`. It doesn't, so the engine looks at `t`'s prototype. `t`'s prototype is `Thing.prototype`, which was assigned to it during the expression `new Thing`. `Thing.prototype` has a `"test"` property, so the value of that ( a function) is used. Then the `()` after it calls that function, which returns the string `"Thing#test"`.

```
console.log(t.toString()); // Logs "[object Object]"
```

The engine looks at `t`, doesn't find a `"toString"` property, so it looks at `t`'s prototype, and doesn't find a `"toString"` property, so it looks at `t`'s prototype's prototype (which is `Object.prototype`). That *does* have a `"toString"` property, whose value is a function. Then `()` calls the function, which returns `"[object Object]"`.

And finally, for completeness:

```
console.log(t.foo());      // Throws an error
```

The engine doesn't find `"foo"` on `t`, `t`'s prototype, or `t`'s prototype's prototype. Now it's out of prototypes, so the expression `t.foo` results in `undefined`. Then we try to call it via `()`, which we can't do because `undefined` is not a function.